# Centering a div inside a Bootstrap column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've got this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EHzm.jpg

I want the espresso machine to be centered inside the column, not next to the next, not attached to the left, but right in the middle.

This is the code I've got ( for some reason the jsfiddle doesn't work so I'm posting it here just for the code ).

```css
#espresso-machine {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #C59989;
  padding: 68px 0  0;
}

#espresso-machine p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 50px 0px 0px;
}

#espresso-machine h4 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Lily Script One', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="espresso-machine">
  <div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/fff" class="hvr-grow">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
      <h4>Espresso machine</h4>
      <p>An espresso machine brews coffee by forcing pressurized water near boiling point through a "puck" of ground coffee and a filter in order to produce a thick, concentrated coffee called espresso. The first machine for making espresso was built and patented in 1884 by Angelo Moriondo of Turin, Italy. An improved design was patented in 1901, which was bought by the founder of the "La Pavoni" company which from 1905 produced espresso machines commercially on a small scale in Milan. <br><br>
        Multiple machine designs have been created to produce espresso. Several machines share some common elements, such as a grouphead and a portafilter. An espresso machine[1] may also have a steam wand which is used to steam and froth liquids, to include milk, for coffee drinks such as cappuccino and caffe latte. Espresso machines may be steam-driven, piston-driven, pump-driven, or air-pump-driven. Machines may be manual or automatic.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jok2c383/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this. updated your fiddle too https://jsfiddle.net/jok2c383/7/

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offsset-3">
            <img src="img/espresso-cappuccino-machine.png" class="hvr-grow">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. This solved it. Thanks a bunch. @Shehroz Asmat

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use flexbox here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jok2c383/15/)

94% coverage http://caniuse.com/flexbox

```
.is-centered {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Images are inline elements, so if you give the parent element the bootstrap class of "text-centre" you are centering any inline elements. This would include text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

As an alternate option to the text-center class, you could add the class "center-block" to the actual image. This makes the image a block element, and centers it with "margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto". Using center-block also means you can also use "img-responsive" and center the image.

Have a look at the bootstrap helper classes for more information:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

Answer (score 0):

Try like this https://jsfiddle.net/jok2c383/17/

i just add new div `image` inside image and add this css:

```
.image {
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100vh;
 flex-flow: column;
}
```